# How to write the compare line with better syntax

Tags: c++

This is my line of code.

Can I replace this with much more graceful syntax?

```
if ( colDiffuseCompare == colDiffuseReplace && colAmbientCompare  ==   colAmbientReplace && colEmissionCompare == colEmissionReplace &&     colSpecularCompare == colSpecularReplace)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {

           return false;
        }
```

Comment: You probably want a struct to group `colDiffuse`, `colAmbient`, `colEmission` and `colSpecular`. And after implementing `operator ==`, simply do `return Compare == Replace;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the `if()` for such case:

```
 return colDiffuseCompare == colDiffuseReplace && 
        colAmbientCompare == colAmbientReplace && 
        colEmissionCompare == colEmissionReplace &&     
        colSpecularCompare == colSpecularReplace;
```

There's no way to avoid combining the single conditions though.

Comment: How about enclosing every comparison in `()` like `(colDiffuseCompare == colDiffuseReplace)` so as to completely avoid `operator associativity` confusions if any.